# PNG\Images - Positioning

Tags: language-agnostic

i have seen people using these kind of images then positioning them so that they are single buttons, you know what i mean

[image] [image]

- Why this is done so ?
- What are the benefits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It spares the browser from issuing lots of little HTTP requests, which slow down page-loads. It also tends to slightly reduce the resource consumption on the browser — which can matter a lot on constrained devices — and is friendlier to constrained caches, because one large image is usually quite a bit smaller than the sum of individual images.

Answer (score 1):

It's called '[css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)' and it's done because of optimalizations.

Like this, the browser only need to load a single (larger) image instead of a lot of small images. This improves the speed of the website.

The single image is usually smaller in size compared to the small images separated.